# How can I efficiently read multiple json files into a Dataframe or JavaRDD?

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

I can use the following code to read a single json file but I need to read multiple json files and merge them into one Dataframe. How can I do this?

```
DataFrame jsondf = sqlContext.read().json("/home/spark/articles/article.json");
```

Or is there a way to read multiple json files into JavaRDD then convert to Dataframe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use exactly the same code to read multiple JSON files. Just pass a path-to-a-directory / path-with-wildcards instead of path to a single file.

`DataFrameReader` also provides [`json` method with a following signature](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/82464fb2e02ca4e4d425017815090497b79dc93f/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L245):

```
json(jsonRDD: JavaRDD[String])
```

which can be used to parse JSON already loaded into `JavaRDD`.

Comment: I think that the json method is deprecated, ought better using the format("json") instead. What do you think?

Comment: Oh, well that's good to know. Thank you! I guess I need to learn to read the documentation better before posting a question.

Answer (score 22):

To read multiple inputs in Spark, use wildcards. That's going to be true whether you're constructing a dataframe or an rdd.

```
context.read().json("/home/spark/articles/*.json")
// or getting json out of s3
context.read().json("s3n://bucket/articles/201510*/*.json")
```

Comment: Thank you, I will be using the s3 eventually but just testing locally right now. I already marked zero323's answer as correct so I could only upvote you.

Answer (score 9):

function `spark.read.json` accepts list of file as a parameter.

```
spark.read.json(List_all_json file)
```

This will read all the files in the list and return a single data frame for all the information in the files.

Comment: Picking up an old thread here, but can anyone comment on the partionability/parallelization optimizations that could be made given >1 input file?   I have a 500GB file that is made up of 10 or 12 ~50GB files and I'd much rather let the smaller files be if in fact that helps the process.

Answer (score 5):

Using pyspark, if you have all the json files in the same folder, you can use `df = spark.read.json('folder_path')`. This instruction will load all the json files inside the folder.

For reading performance, I recommend you for providing dataframe the schema:

```py
import pyspark.sql.types as T

billing_schema = billing_schema = T.StructType([
  T.StructField('accountId', T.LongType(),True),
  T.StructField('accountName',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('accountOwnerEmail',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('additionalInfo',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('chargesBilledSeparately',T.BooleanType(),True),
  T.StructField('consumedQuantity',T.DoubleType(),True),
  T.StructField('consumedService',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('consumedServiceId',T.LongType(),True),
  T.StructField('cost',T.DoubleType(),True),
  T.StructField('costCenter',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('date',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('departmentId',T.LongType(),True),
  T.StructField('departmentName',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('instanceId',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('location',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('meterCategory',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('meterId',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('meterName',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('meterRegion',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('meterSubCategory',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('offerId',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('partNumber',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('product',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('productId',T.LongType(),True),
  T.StructField('resourceGroup',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('resourceGuid',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('resourceLocation',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('resourceLocationId',T.LongType(),True),
  T.StructField('resourceRate',T.DoubleType(),True),
  T.StructField('serviceAdministratorId',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('serviceInfo1',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('serviceInfo2',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('serviceName',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('serviceTier',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('storeServiceIdentifier',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('subscriptionGuid',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('subscriptionId',T.LongType(),True),
  T.StructField('subscriptionName',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('tags',T.StringType(),True),
  T.StructField('unitOfMeasure',T.StringType(),True)
])

billing_df = spark.read.json('/mnt/billingsources/raw-files/202106/', schema=billing_schema)
```

Comment: on the documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) I couldn't find the second schema parameter for loading json. Are you sure about it?

Comment: @Prometheus here is the documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json.html?highlight=json#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json

Answer (score 0):

Function `json(String... paths)` takes variable arguments. ([documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json-java.lang.String...-))

So you can change your code like this:

```scala
sqlContext.read().json(file1, file2, ...)
```