# Unable to load multiple json files with pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am fairly new to pyspark and am trying to load data from a folder which contains multiple json files.However the load fails. Here is the code that I am using:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]") \
                .appName('SparkByExamples.com') \
                .getOrCreate()
spark.read.json('file_directory/*')
```

I am getting error as :
Exception in thread "globPath-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-57" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

[image: Error]

I tried setting the path variables for hadoop and spark as well but still no use.
However, if I load a single file from the directory, it loads perfectly.
Can someone please tell me what is going wrong in this case.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710898/how-can-i-efficiently-read-multiple-json-files-into-a-dataframe-or-javardd

Comment: I have tried that but still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I can successfully read all CSV under a directory without adding the *asterik*.
I think you should try

```
spark.read.json('file_directory/')
```

Comment: I have tried that too, it doesn't seem to work for me. I am still getting unsatisfied Link error

Comment: As described by @Nemetaarion.
The UnsatisfiedLinkError exception on Java native method was raised because of version incompatibility between the Hadoop version in SBT dependencies and winutils.exe (HDFS wrapper) on my Windows machine.
Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696990/unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-apache-spark-when-writing-parquet-to-aws-s3-using-stagin).

Comment: I had tried that too but still am getting the error