# Dynamically reading in 1m > JSON files into Pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have managed to read in all the files and create the tables manually based on the JSON schema.  However, I am unsure how to do this dynamically, i.e. if any changes to the json files the values are read in automatically based on the json schema.

**Manually:**

```
df=spark.read.json("path/*millionsofjson.json")
```

**Reviewed nested schema**

```
df.printSchema
```

**Reading in Metadata Table**

```
df_table1=df.select("metadata")

df_table1_select=("df_table1.column1","df_table1.column2"..."df_table1.column20")

df_table1_select.show()
```

**Reading in Orders Table**

```
df_table2=df.select("metadata")

df_table2_select=("df_table1.column1","df_table1.column2"..."df_table1.column50")

df_table2_select.show()
```

**Reading in Sales Table**

```
df_table2=df.select("metadata")

df_table2_select=("df_table1.column1","df_table1.column2"..."df_table1.column35")

df_table2_select.show()
```

Hopefully, this explains what I am after...

Comment: You have all files of various tables,  mixed in one place, you create a single dataframe and then you create from it multiple tables, by picking the relevant fields for each table?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround may help you out to achieve the above requirement:

You can list all of your multiple json files if they are stored in one/same folder by using below cmd:

```
df = spark.read.json('give the folder_path where all of your files are stored')
```

For more information please refer this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710898/how-can-i-efficiently-read-multiple-json-files-into-a-dataframe-or-javardd) as suggested by @[*Camilo Soto*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6281442/camilo-soto) & this [***Blog***](https://medium.com/@thomaspt748/how-to-flatten-json-files-dynamically-using-apache-spark-scala-version-9cc9560631dd)